Square Crossing - Question about conditioning
Question: A square of side length 20 is formed in front of you. You select a point uniformly at random from the interior of the square. You then proceed to form a circle of radius $R\sim\operatorname{Unif}(0,10)$, independent of the point selected. Find the probability that the circle you create does not intersect the square at any point.
I know the best way to approach this would be to fix r which would yield a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$, but I am trying to solve the question by fixing X and Y first. However I get the incorrect answer of $\frac{1}{4}$. Here is my method:

The prob we want is $P(R<\min(X, 20-X, Y, 20-Y) = P(R<X, R<20-X, R<Y, R<20-Y)$
Due to the independence of $X$ and $Y$, we get $= P(R<X, R<20-X)P(R<Y, R<20-Y)$
Because $X$ and $Y$ are both identically distributed, this simplifies to $[P(R<X, R<20-X)]^2$
Condition on when $X \le 10$ and $X /ge 11)$: This reduces the probability $P(R<X, R<20-X)$ to $P(R<X|X \le 10)$ and $P(R<20-X|X \ge 11)$ i.e. $P(R<X, R<20-X) = \int_{0}^{10}P(R<X|X \le 10) f_X(x)dx + \int_{0}^{10}P(R<X|X \ge 11) f_X(x)dx$
$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{20}$, $P(R<X|X \le 10) = \frac{1}{10}$ and $P(R<X|X \ge 11) = \frac{1}{10}$ so solving the integral gives $\frac{1}{2}$
So our answer is $(\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{4}$

Once again I know how to do the question by fixing R but I am interested in understanding how to do it by fixing the positions of X and Y first.

wlog consider the square centered at the origin with side length $2$ - at the same time, $R\sim \textrm{Uniform}(0,1)$. Now consider that the diagonals of the square partition it into four equal triangles - in particular, the probability of $(X,Y)$ falling into any of them is $\frac{1}{4}$. Call the left triangle $T$. If $(X,Y)$ falls in $T$, then the circle does not intersect the square iff $R<X+1$, and we know that $P(R<1+x)=1+x$ for all $x\in [-1,0]$. So, since $R\perp (X,Y)$,
$$P(R<1+X,(X,Y)\in T)=E[(1+X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X<0,X<Y<-X\}}]$$
We also know that $X,Y$ can be taken as IID uniform in $[-1,1]$. Thus we also get
$$E[(1+X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X<0,X<Y<-X\}}]=E[(-X)(1+X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X<0\}}]=\frac{1}{12}$$
By symmetry the same holds for the other three triangles. We conclude by summing up: $\frac{4}{12}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Your second step is wrong. $R$ is also random, so the events $R < \min(X, 20 - X)$ and $R < \min(Y, 20 - Y)$ are not necessarily independent, even if $X$ and $Y$ are.

(I did not downvote) This should be a comment in my opinion.
